# How do I remove an element and its content from an XML file

Tags: php, html, regex, xml

Below is the text I need to remove `<w:drawing>` tags and its content from

```
<w:document>
<w:t>some text here</w:t>
<w:drawing>drawing image</w:drawing>
</w:document>
```

i tried this

```
$result = preg_replace('/<w:drawing\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/w:drawing>/i', '', $xml);
```

but stil getting `<w:drawing>` tags, any suggestion?

in result i want get

```
<w:document>
<w:t>some text here</w:t>
</w:document>
```

Comment: What do you get for `$result` ?

Comment: in result i want get
<w:document>
 <w:t>some text here</w:t>
</w:document>

Comment: Is `$xml` a string ? Your code works for me if it does (apart from newlines)

Comment: yes, it's a string, i have re-check my code and works..

Comment: That is good. You should close your question because it is working.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I found new problem, 
<w:drawing> its have some multilevel tag inside, like:

 <w:drawing>
<wp:inline>
<a:graphic>
<pic:pic></pic:pic>
</a:graphic>
</wp:inline>
</:w:drawing>

and my script not working, my script only working on single level xml tag.

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` to do that.

Comment: Does this represent your input?  https://regex101.com/r/9O3enL/4 Please edit your question to post a best-likeness of your actual input data.  And show exactly the output you want to generate from the new input.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You just need to replace your regex pattern with something like this

```
$result = preg_replace('/<w:drawing>.*<\/w:drawing>/', '', $xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've got here is not a complete XML document, so I've made some changes to it. Regardless, NEVER try to parse XML with regular expressions. **NEVER!!**

Here's a quick example using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), though [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) would work just as well:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="w">
    <w:t>some text here</w:t>
    <w:drawing>drawing image</w:drawing>
</w:document>
XML;
$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, 0, false, "w");
$doc->registerXPathNamespace("w", "w");
$drawings = $doc->xpath("//w:drawing");
foreach ($drawings as &$drawing) {
    unset($drawing[0]);
}
$new_xml = $doc->asXML();
echo $new_xml;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="w">
    <w:t>some text here</w:t>

</w:document>
```